# jboss-service.xml could not be opened, does it exist?

Tags: web-applications, jboss

When I am going to launch jBoss I see this erorr , so jBoss could not be started, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Which jboss version do you use?

In the instance\conf\bootstrap\profile.xml, check that the jboss-service.xml path is correct.

If you don't have jboss-service.xml in the instance\conf, I think you have to download jboss again http://www.jboss.org/jbossas/downloads/

Comment: Version 4.0.5 . Yes you are right , at the moment I have jboss-service.xml in the folder "D:\jBoss\server\default\conf" and the error is changed to                                                         14:57:06,047 ERROR [MainDeployer] Could not create deployment: file:/D:/jBoss/se
rver/default/conf/jboss-service.xml
org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Trying to install an already registere
d mbean: jboss.system:service=MainDeployer

Comment: @Hadi Do you have space in path (at least at your comment there is: `file:/D:/jBoss/se rver/`)? In that place it souldn't be any space.

Comment: @Hadi Ypou talk about "D:\jBoss\server\default\conf" but the log talks about "D:\jBoss\se rver\default\conf". there is a space in "se rver".

Otherwise in "D:\jBoss\server\default\conf\bootstrap\profile.xml", check that the jboss-service.xml path is correct.